# How can I pause execution of a C#.NET program?

Tags: c#, .net

I have Desktop Application There is a button Pause.
I want to pause Program on button click.
I am using Thread. Thread.suspend is not working Please give me idea to solve this.

Comment: Also what are you pausing? Are you pausing a long running operation, is your task being executed on a separate thread?

Answer (score 1):

This will pause the thread that called it until is_paused is false. This what you need?

```
while(is_paused)
    Thread.Sleep(sleep_time);
```